Proof standard when custom flagging spam
I recently flagged a post using a custom flag to show undisclosed affiliation, and it was declined. In the flag message, I said

Undisclosed affiliation. See medium.com/@skpcsmtp, showing "vvcares" with similar username.

The response was

Having a Medium Blog is not an affiliation. Medium is a blogging platform. The core code is also in the answer so links are acceptable as supplementary material. [...]

The point of linking to it was to show that the user's name was tied to the domain, not that they simply owned a Medium blog. That page also links to this article, which is more explicit about it.
I'd understand more if the response is that this is not definitive enough to prove the affiliation, but I really don't see how I can read the response this way. Even if this was the case, I'd also disagree with this since the string of characters is too particular to be coincidental. Should I have been more specific?

Also, I can be found in Charcoal HQ where this first popped up. I'm sure several of us would agree that this was spam.
